# Splitting up a deck list using a Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm reading a deck list from a file and want to break this up into 3 sections. The quantity, the card name and the set. The set code is in the brackets. Here is an example of the data I have:

```
1 Dead Revels [RNA]
7 Final Payment [RNA]
1 Ob Nixilis's Cruelty [WAR]
1 Aid the Fallen [WAR]
13 Makeshift Battalion [WAR]
1 Sunblade Angel [WAR]
34 Trusted Pegasus [WAR]
1 Orzhov Racketeers [RNA]
1 Wanderer's Strike [WAR]
1 Reya Dawnbringer [UMA]
4 Expansion // Explosion [GRN]
```

This is the code so far:

```
while (($buffer = fgets($file, 4096)) !== false) {
preg_match_all("#[0-9]+\s[a-zA-Z']+(?:[\w -]*[a-zA-Z']+)#", $buffer, $matches);
$count = count($matches[1]);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
```

...

Comment: Do you have a `#` at the start of the regex? I think you omitted it by mistake.

Comment: Try `preg_match_all('~^([0-9]+)\s+(.*?)\s*\[([^][]+)]$~m', $text, $matches)`, see https://regex101.com/r/G9fQSH/1

Comment: Yes, I do have  the # at the beginning. When I posted the question I put in the expression that worked the most and missed the #.

Comment: So, does https://3v4l.org/tfut0 work as you expect?

Comment: No it doesn't. The arrays are empty. Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [0] =>

Comment: Please post the contents of `$buffer`

Comment: Looks like $buffer gets one line at a time. $buffer="1 Dead Revels [RNA]" But the array still comes out with nothing.
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) [3] => Array ( ) ) 0

Comment: I am not sure what array you mean See https://3v4l.org/hoBcP, you get all the values you need. Add full code you have. What exact output do you want to get?

Comment: $buffer is filled from a fgets. Full code at https://3v4l.org/Qkj6s but the important part starts at line 136

Comment: Well, are you sure the strings look exactly like you posted? Try without anchors, `if (preg_match('~([0-9]+)\s+(.*?)\s*\[([^][]+)]~', $buffer, $matches)) {
    print_r(array_slice($matches, 1));
  }`

Comment: Also, `var regex = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(" + fileType + ")$");` is wrong. Use `var regex = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9\\s_\\\\.:-]+(" + fileType + ")$");`

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
([0-9]+)\s+(.*?)\s*\[([^][]+)]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G9fQSH/3).

**Details**

- `([0-9]+)` - Group 1: 1+ digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `([^][]+)` - Group 3: 1+ chars other than `]` and `[`
- `]` - a `]` char.

See [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/CLNBs):

```
if (preg_match('~([0-9]+)\s+(.*?)\s*\[([^][]+)]~', $buffer, $matches)) {
    print_r(array_slice($matches, 1)); 
}
```